# Split string in Ocaml - but not when delimiter is escaped by backslash

Tags: regex, split, escaping, ocaml

**Goal:** To be able to split the following string: `"command/test \/ escaped/"`

Into the following List: `["command", "test / escaped"]`

**Current regexp** looks like:

`Str.split (Str.regexp "/") string_to_split;;`

Which is too simplisitc and I need to escape by preceding the string with backslash(es).

**I tried** this one: `Str.regexp "((?!\\).)/"` but it does not work with the Ocaml parser yielding: `uncaught exception Failure("spurious \) in regular expression")`

Any ideas?

I should mention, I've noticed the Ocaml-parser automatically escapes backslashes in strings, so a string like:
`"foobar\/barfoo"` is converted to `"foobar\\/barfoo"`. So maybe one actually want to remove all even-numbered backslashes in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes twice:

- once for the string content
- once for the regexp

So the correct regexp would be `Str.regexp "((?!\\\\).)/"`.

However, that regexp won't work.

I suggest instead 3 other solutions:

- do the search and split manually using `match_beginning` etc.,
- use a simple split with the `'/'` character, and recompose strings as needed,
- replace the `\\/` characters by another combination, say `\\§` (or some other string unlikely to appear in the text you wish to process), do your split, and then do the reverse replacement in each substring (this time only replacing the '§' with '/').

The last one is probably the fastest, if you have a good replacement character for `'/'` in `"\\/"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly less obvious solution:

```
let rec split s = Scanf.sscanf s "%s@/%s@\n" (fun left right ->
  let llen = String.length left in
  let (left, escaped) = 
    if llen > 0 && left.[llen - 1] = '\\' then
      (String.sub left 0 (llen - 1), true) 
    else
      (left, false) in
  if right = "" then
    [left]
  else match split right with
    h :: t when escaped ->
      (left ^ "/" ^ h) :: t|
    ht ->
      left :: ht         
);;
```

And the output:

```
# split "command/test \\/ escaped/";;
- : string list = ["command"; "test / escaped"]
```

It's a bit too cryptic, but does the job nevertheless.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, ***Str.regexp*** does not support `!` construct.

However, [PCRE-OCaml](https://bitbucket.org/mmottl/pcre-ocaml) library does:

```
# #directory "+pcre";;
# #load "pcre.cma";;
# Pcre.split 
    ~rex:(Pcre.regexp ~flags:[`EXTENDED] "(?<!\\\\)/")
    "command/test \\/ escaped/"
  ;;
- : string list = ["command"; "test \\/ escaped"]
```

If you want to get rid of `\/` string escapes, you will either have to post-process result of *split* or (better) use *match* and build that list yourself.